# I am using a method with a stored procedure, but it's always returning false

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, methods

I am using bool method with Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2005.

When I am passing correct details and click `loginButton`, the code always returns false from the stored procedure.

This is my stored procedure in SQL Server 2005:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserCheckLoginDetails]
    (@IsLoginIdCorrect BIT OUTPUT,
     @IsPasswordCorrect BIT OUTPUT,
     @LoginID NVARCHAR(200),
     @Password NVARCHAR(20)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET @IsLoginIdCorrect = 0
    SET @IsPasswordCorrect = 0

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserInfo 
               WHERE loginid = @LoginID AND password = @Password)
    BEGIN
        SET @IsLoginIdCorrect = 1
        SET @IsPasswordCorrect = 1
    END
    ELSE
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE loginid = @LoginID)
        BEGIN
            SET @IsLoginIdCorrect = 1
        END
END
```

This is my method returning `True` or `False`:

```vb
Private Sub GetIsUserLoginCorrect(IsLoginIdCorrect As Boolean, IsPasswordCorrect As Boolean)
    Using Conn As New SqlConnection(_SqlCon)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UserCheckLoginDetails", Conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Conn.Open()

            'OutPut Parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsLoginIdCorrect", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsPasswordCorrect", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

            'InPut Parameters
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", LoginIDTextBox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordTextBox.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ' Assign Parameters
            IsLoginIdCorrect = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters("@IsLoginIdCorrect").Value)
            IsPasswordCorrect = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters("@IsPasswordCorrect").Value)

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

This is the Login button click event handler, even when I provide the correct values, it still always returns false:

```vb
Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    Try
        Dim IsLoginIdCorrect, IsPasswordCorrect As Boolean
        GetIsUserLoginCorrect(IsLoginIdCorrect, IsPasswordCorrect)

        If IsLoginIdCorrect And IsPasswordCorrect = True Then
            Me.Hide()
            ' User Information
            DeshBoard.MainUserIdLabel.Text = Me.MainUserIdLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.UserNameLabel.Text = Me.UserNameLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.UserLoginIdLabel.Text = Me.UserLoginIdLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.UserLevelLabel.Text = Me.UserLevelLabel.Text
            'Organanization Information
            DeshBoard.MainOrgIDLabel.Text = Me.MainOrgIDLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.OrgNameLabel.Text = Me.OrgNameLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.OrgTelLabel.Text = Me.OrgTelLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.OrgEmailLabel.Text = Me.OrgEmailLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.OrgAddressLabel.Text = Me.OrgAddressLabel.Text
            DeshBoard.Show()
        Else
            If IsLoginIdCorrect = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Login ID is not correct...!!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                LoginIDTextBox.Clear()
                PasswordTextBox.Clear()
                LoginIDTextBox.Focus()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Password ID is not correct...!!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                PasswordTextBox.Clear()
                PasswordTextBox.Focus()
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As ApplicationException
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ByRef` to both arguments in Sub `GetIsUserLoginCorrect()`.
To demonstrate, try the following with and without `ByRef`.

```vb
Private Sub ChangeBoolean(ByRef TorF As Boolean)
    TorF = True
End Sub
Private Sub OPCode2()
    Dim TorF As Boolean
    ChangeBoolean(TorF)
    Debug.Print(TorF.ToString) ' Result False without ByRef in ChangeBoolean
    'When ByRef is added result is True
End Sub
```

Comment: Good to see that you passed me :)

Comment: Hi @zackraiyan. Good to see you. Did you get a job. I am guessing you are very busy.

Comment: @Mary , no i didn't get a job. I am working on my online project. I just did a search on SO for your name to see if you are still here, i was glad to find you !

Answer (score 1):

First off, a method can refer to either a sub or a function. A sub is a method that performs an action.  A function is a method that calculates or retrieves one or more values.

A sub should not be called Getxxx, because its primary purpose should not be returning a value.

A function should be used to return values.  Since you are trying to retrieve multiple values, if you were using 2017 I would suggest returning a named tuple with your two values, since you aren’t I would create an object that has the values and return that.

On a totally different note, you really can’t tell the difference between right user wrong password and wrong user right password and wrong user wrong password - so you shouldn’t tell someone you can.  You just say login unsuccessful login, or invalid username/password combination.

Answer (score 1):

**There's a lot wrong with your code.**

Firstly, why are you using so much of SQL code ? Correct me if i am wrong : You are trying to build a log in system. So much of SQL code or even the stored procedure is worthless here. You can simply write the SQL statements in your code by using the `SqlCommand` class. Even though you are using the `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement, i can surely say that things can be simplified here.

You are also using the `Me` keyword. It's not C# where the use of `this`(same as `Me` in VB.Net) becomes compulsory. I assume it's a `Windows Forms Application` and if that's so, then using `Me` keyword to access it's child elements wouldn't result in any different if it's not used at all.

The next worth mentioning issues is your **Name Conventions**. Most or should i say all of your variables have the same name. For example : `IsLoginIdCorrect` - used both as a parameter of a method and also a variable inside a method.

The next issues is in these two lies :

```
Dim IsLoginIdCorrect, IsPasswordCorrect As Boolean
GetIsUserLoginCorrect(IsLoginIdCorrect, IsPasswordCorrect)
```

You are passing the boolean variables before they have been assigned any value. You are lucky it's not C# or this wouldn't even compile. Passing the boolean variables without assigning any value will, by default, set their values to `False`. So, literally, you are always passing the same value in which case, the outcome will always be the same.

The next issue is in your `If` statement inside your `LoginButton_Click` method aka LoginButton's click event handler's method :

```
If IsLoginIdCorrect And IsPasswordCorrect = True Then
```

The if statements, if described in simple words, means : *If `IsLoginIdCorrect` and `IsPasswordCorrect` are true, then proceed...*. So, in this case, `IsPasswordCorrect = True` doesn't affect much. However, this is not the best practice too. You should better follow the following coding rule while using `If` statements:

```
 If (IsLoginIdCorrect = True AndAlso IsPasswordCorrect = True) Then
```

`AndAlso` operators evaluates each side just like the `And` operator. The difference is that it would return `False` if the left side(`IsLoginIdCorrect`, in this case) returns `False`.

The next issues is the usage of `ApplicationException`. I don't understand why, in this era, you are using that class! This class is usually used to derive from and create `exception`s. You can simply use `Exception` instead of `ApplicationException`.

Your `Try-Catch` block seems not useful as well. All of your codes inside the `LoginButton_Click` are in `If` conditions and they perform very basic operation. It is unlikely to ever throw any exception at all.

Your logics, for most part, are illogical(sorry to put it this way). In your `GetIsUserLoginCorrect` method, you are setting `IsLoginIdCorrect` and `IsPasswordCorrect` to either true or false but it wouldn't matter because they are parameters of the method itself. So even if you set their values, they will be reset when you call the method again. The reason why `ByRef` (according to Mary's answer) works is because `ByRef`, in short, means that you are pointing to original variable that you passed(not it's copy).

**And finally, the solution you are looking for....**

Even though i see you have marked Mary's answer as *the answer*, i would like to help you out a bit as-well.

Firstly, get rid of the stored procedure if possible and also if you are not using it anywhere else. I see you are using the `If Exist` condition inside your SQL queries. This is actually a nice move because according to performance reports, checking if data exists in a database/table using `IF EXISTS` yields the fastest output. So bravo for that one. But if you follow my advice and want to ditch the stored procedure, then you need to get rid of the `IF EXISTS` statement as well. Rather, you can simply use the `SELECT` statement itself, use the `ExecuteScalar` method of the `SqlCommand` class, convert it's value to `Integer` and check if the value of the `Integer` is **1** or not.

Example :

```
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserInfo 
           WHERE loginid = @LoginID AND password = @Password")
Dim Exists = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
If Exists = 1 Then
''Code if data exists
End if
```

**Note that** i have used `Convert.ToInt32` here. This will prevent `null-reference` exception as when `ExecuteScalar` returns `Null`, it will be converted to `0` integer value.

Also, why are you using `GetIsUserLoginCorrect` as method ? You can simply use it as a function and return required values. As you are returning multiple values, you can easily use the `Tuple` type as your function's type:

```
Private Function GetIsUserLoginCorrect(IsLoginIdCorrect As Boolean, IsPasswordCorrect As Boolean) As Tuple(of Boolean, Boolean)
....
....
return Tuple.Create(IsLoginIdCorrect, IsPasswordCorrect)
End Sub
```

**Usage**

```
 Dim IsLoginCorrect = GetIsUserLoginCorrect(first_boolean_variable,second_boolean_variable).Item1

  Dim IsPasswordCorrect = GetIsUserLoginCorrect(first_boolean_variable,second_boolean_variable).Item2
```

One last thing. As you are showing `DeshBoard` form after hiding the main form, make sure to call `MainForm.Close` on the `Dashboard` form's `Closing`/`Closed` event. This will ensure the application's exit(unless you have other plans for the main form, of course).

Hope this answer helps you.